# Inline gcc assembly and local variables (double)

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, att

I'm trying to use the inline *asm* directive of gcc/g++ (I have to say I've been using the Intel syntax on *MSVC* previously and that was a *breeze*).
I'm playing around with *double* values and the following *my_func2* seems to crash after execution:

```
  #include <iostream>

  void my_func(const double *in, double *out) {
    asm("mov %0, %%r8" : : "r"(in));
    asm("movupd (%%r8), %%xmm0" :);
    asm("movupd (%%r8), %%xmm1" :);
    asm("addpd %%xmm1, %%xmm0" :);
    asm("movupd %%xmm0, (%0)" : : "r"(out) : "%r8", "%xmm0", "%xmm1");
  }

  double my_func2(const double *in) {
    double  ret = 0.0;

    asm("mov %0, %%r8" : : "r"(in));
    asm("movupd (%%r8), %%xmm0" :);
    asm("movupd (%%r8), %%xmm1" :);
    asm("addpd %%xmm1, %%xmm0" :);
    asm("movupd %%xmm0, %0" : "=m"(ret) : : "memory", "%r8", "%xmm0", "%xmm1");

    return ret;
 }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const double    a = 1.0;
    double      b = 0.0;
    my_func(&a, &b);
    std::cout << "b:" << b << std::endl;
    b = my_func2(&a);
    std::cout << "b:" << b << std::endl;
  }
```

The error I get is specifically (when I'm running with *gdb*):

```
Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
0x00000000004008e1 in main (argc=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x400fffffffffffec>, 
    argv=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x400fffffffffffe0>) at asm_test.cpp:28
28      b = my_func2(&a);
```

What am I doing wrong? In the last line of *my_func2* I've specified that *memory* is clobbered too, I don't understand...
Where can I find a good guide how to use the infamous AT&T syntax?
I compile with: `g++ -g -o asm_test asm_test.cpp`, *g++* version *g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3* on Ubuntu *Linux scv 3.2.0-48-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 19:43:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux*.

I've found http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html and http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/brennan/brennan_att_inline_djgpp.html , is there something *more* you would recommend?

Thanks,
Ema

Comment: Don't _need_ those flags to compile and make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake here is that one has to be careful when using `movupd`. With this instruction, you actually copy 128 bit of memory, in *and* out.

By chance the first function can copy these values out too, but the second one, has got *only* 64 bit space in `ret` variable. As expected this corrupts stack, yields to undefined behaviour?
Substituting `movupd` with `movlpd` (or `movhpd`), things work *a charm*.

Am I still clobbering the right registers?

Following code works *just fine* when compiled with `g++ -O3 -o asm_test asm_test.cpp`

```
  void my_func(const double *in, double *out) {
    asm ("mov %0, %%r8" : : "r"(in));
    asm ("movhpd (%%r8), %%xmm0" :);
    asm ("movhpd (%%r8), %%xmm1" :);
    asm ("addpd %%xmm1, %%xmm0" :);
    asm ("movhpd %%xmm0, (%0)" : : "r"(out) : "memory", "%r8", "%xmm0", "%xmm1");
  }

  double my_func2(const double *in) {
    double  ret;

    asm("mov %0, %%r8" : : "r"(in));
    asm("movlpd (%%r8), %%xmm0" :);
    asm("movlpd (%%r8), %%xmm1" :);
    asm("addpd %%xmm1, %%xmm0" :);
    asm("movlpd %%xmm0, %0" : "=m"(ret) : : "memory", "%r8", "%xmm0", "%xmm1");

    return ret;
  }
```

Comment: The `asm("..." : )` is a little trick to work around the fact that gcc will _throw out your inline assembly_ if written like this (using multiple separate lines of `asm()` statements that are _not independent_). It's probably better to re-write this.

Comment: I knew this would have been the case... probably I should use `volatile` too (this should force the compiler to leave it as it is. Or as you suggest rewrite it in one statement. Anyway using `movupd` instead of any _lower_ / _high_ half was the _real_ issue... Btw I've done a bit of analysis in rewriting a `sum` function for large double datasets and when I was looking at generated _asm_ it was as expected (but I have to say I've encapsulated the functions into `__attribute__ ((noinline))`).

Answer (score 1):

gcc inline assembly doesn't particularly like it if you have *separate* lines of `asm()` statements that are *not actually independent*. You'd better code the above like:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h> // for __m128d

static  void my_func(const double *in, double *out) {
    asm("movupd %1, %%xmm0\n"
        "movupd %1, %%xmm1\n"
        "addpd %%xmm1, %%xmm0\n"
        "movupd %%xmm0, %0"
        : "=rm"(*(__m128d*)out)
        : "rm"(*(__m128d*)in)
        : "%xmm0", "%xmm1");
}

static double my_func2(const double *in) {
    double ret;
    asm("movupd %1, %%xmm0\n"
        "movupd %1, %%xmm1\n"
        "addpd %%xmm1, %%xmm0\n"
        "movlpd %%xmm0, %0"
        : "=xm"(ret)
        : "rm"(*(__m128d*)in)
        : "%xmm0", "%xmm1");
    return ret;
}
```

because this lets the compiler choose where to put things (mem or reg). For your source, this inlines the following two blocks into `main()`:

```
  1c:   66 0f 10 44 24 10       movupd 0x10(%rsp),%xmm0
  22:   66 0f 10 4c 24 10       movupd 0x10(%rsp),%xmm1
  28:   66 0f 58 c1             addpd  %xmm1,%xmm0
  2c:   66 0f 11 44 24 20       movupd %xmm0,0x20(%rsp)
[ ... ]
  63:   66 0f 10 44 24 10       movupd 0x10(%rsp),%xmm0
  69:   66 0f 10 4c 24 10       movupd 0x10(%rsp),%xmm1
  6f:   66 0f 58 c1             addpd  %xmm1,%xmm0
  73:   66 0f 13 44 24 08       movlpd %xmm0,0x8(%rsp)
```

This is _not optimal, though ... if you change it to:

```
static  void my_func(const double *in, double *out) {
    asm volatile("movapd %1, %0\n"
                 "addpd %1, %0"
                 : "=xm"((__m128d*)out)
                 : "x"(*(__m128d*)in));
}
```

you leave it to the compiler where to put the variables. The compiler detects that it can get away with not doing loads/stores at all ... as this gets inlined simply as:

```
  18:   66 0f 28 c1             movapd %xmm1,%xmm0
  1c:   66 0f 58 c1             addpd  %xmm1,%xmm0
```

since the compiler recognizes it's got all variables in registers / wants all returns in registers.

Although it's not at all necessary to do this using assembly; with a decent compiler (your gcc will do) the plain C/C++ version,

```
static void my_func(const double *in, double *out) {
    out[0] = in[0] + in[0];
    out[1] = in[1] + in[1];
}
```

is most likely going to be turned into no less efficient code.

Comment: Question: do you think the crash was not due to the fact I was supposed to be operating on 128 bit instead of 64? Additionally, from some tests, the above of the C/C++ loop might be true just in some cases and only when I compile with `-march=native` though.

Comment: In your specific example, yes you did cause the crash by writing 128bits into the location of `ret`, because the compiler in all likelihood created a memory layout on the stack like `struct stk stk = { double ret; void *savedfp; void *retaddr }`, and you've been blotting the caller's framepointer over. On return from your function, the caller, `main`, will crash on next framepointer-relative memory access.

Comment: Thanks FrankH, just to be consistent with question asked I'll promote my answer, still I'll treasure you recommendations.